# How should I build a server for mobile-apps

Tags: server, backend, mobile-application

I'm planning to build an application that will include users registration and so on.. I want to build a kind of social network application and i wonder how should I build my server and what is the right way to connect between the application and the server?
I know to build clients and servers in python and connect between them with sockets, but I realise that this is not the right way to do it in mobile applications..
someone told me I should learn something called SOA or web application server , I did not understand him so well,
I hope that you understand what I search for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start is to create a REST-based backend service that exposes methods/operations via HTTP. Host the service on your server, and allow the app to communicate with the service. This service can send and receive data, typically in the JSON format, between the service and your app(s). Try looking here for some examples:

Python: https://www.sitepoint.com/building-simple-rest-api-mobile-applications/

.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api